# write a program to find that a column have only integer value in it with regex in python

Tags: python

```
import csv
import re

column_3 =[]

f = open('E:\pythontest\ip_data.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
     column_3.append(row[2])

f.close

print column_3

for row in column_3:

    if re.search(r'\d.*' , 'column_3'):
        print("its numeric value")
    else:
        print ("its not numeric")
```

I am doing this but it prints its numeric for all data ,while there is a row that contains string not integer.

Comment: Please extract a minimal but complete example. That said, consider upgrading to Python 3. At least I wouldn't bother learning an old Python version that's slowly fading into oblivion.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you have already read the data from csv into `column_3`. To check if all the values in this column have integer data, you can use `all` with regex match:

```
>>> import re

>>> column_3 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', 'a']
>>> all(re.match(r'^\d+$', c) for c in column_3)
False

>>> column_3 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '56']
>>> all(re.match(r'^\d+$', c) for c in column_3)
True

>>> column_3 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '56', 'a43']
>>> all(re.match(r'^\d+$', c) for c in column_3)
False
```

`^\d+$` will make sure to match a string which have only digits. I also added start and end assertions so it doesn't capture anything in between.

Answer (score 0):

While reading the file Try appending it in a string format.

```
for row in csv_f:
    column_3.append(str(row[2]))
```

Hope it helps.Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex for matching only numeric digits isn't right. `\d.*` tries to match a digit followed by 0 or more chars(any).

Also there is no need to store the column values into a separate list and iterate it again. Instead you can check for it inside the `reader` loop itself like this:

```
import csv, re

flag=True
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if not re.match(r'^\d+$', row[1]) is not None:
            print('All not Numeric')
            break
    else:
        print('All Numeric')
```

regex `^\d+$` or `^[0-9]+$` will match 1 or more digits.

Here are 2 sample test cases:

```
$ cat data
a,1
b,123
c,456
d,56
$ python3 a.py 
All Numeric
$ vim data
$ cat data
a,1
b,123
c,456
d,56s
$ python a.py 
All not Numeric
```